# Can't find element in webpage using selenium C#?

Tags: c#, selenium, iframe

Can't find any element in the page have 2 iframes nested in selenium?

When the first start, I find all element in the browser but when to go to iframe[0] I can't find any element in the browser.

My code like:

```
var iframes = browser.FindElementsByXPathName("//iframe[contains(@id,'container_page')]");
while (browser.FindElementsByXPathName("//span[contains(@class, 'button_Love')]").Count == 0 && iframes.Count == 0)
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
if (iframes.Count > 0)
{
    browser.GoToFrame(iframes[0]);
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try following code.

```
   var driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("you URL");
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
        //check if there is any iframe then get that frame and switch on frame using folloiwng code.
        var frame = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.Id("frame_id")));
        driver.SwitchTo().Frame(frame);
        var elementbutton_Love = driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("button_Love"));

        //after doing all work you can go to default content using  following code
        driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
```

if any issue then let me know.